# How to generate batches in Keras for contrastive learning to ensure positive pairs are together?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am training a neural network that I implemented using Keras. My model uses contrastive learning to learn embeddings: (video) inputs with the same label are positive pairs and should have similar embeddings, while negative pairs should have dissimilar embeddings.

What I would like to do is make sure that the batches group positive pairs together. That is, if I have the labels `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2]` and I want two batches, one way to split the labels would be into one batch with labels `[0,0,1,1,1]` and one with `[0,0,2,2]`. The first batch now contains the pairs `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` (between all instances of label 1), while the second batch contains pairs `(0,0)` and `(2,2)`.

I think this would be achievable by making sure that no batch contains any label only once. Taking my example labels from above, I want to try and avoid a batch like `[0,0,1,2,2]` (where label 1 occurs only once in the batch). However, I have no idea how I would implement a batch generator to do something like this. Any help with implementing this would be greatly appreciated. Hints about what this batch generation strategy is called are also welcome, because I have not been able to find if it has a specific name.

I tried using the standard batch generation that Keras uses, but my model does not learn to make the positive embeddings that similar.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please wrap your arrays and tuples with the code formatting wrappers? That will help make your question easier to read.

Comment: @AkilanManivannan fair point! I added some code wrappers, I hope this helps with the readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ds.group_by_window` method where you set the `window_size==2`, and then `unbatch` and `batch` to required `batch_size`. This will make sure that latest 2 elements of each class will be there in each batch.

Example,

```
labels = np.random.randint(0, high=3, size=(20,))
features = ['feat_' + str(i) for i in np.arange(len(labels))]
#labels : [2, 2, 0, 1, ... 0, 1, 1, 2]
#features : ['feat_0','feat_1','feat_2',...'feat_19']
```

Group by window, so that each class is grouped by pairs,

```
 window_size = 2
 ds = ds.group_by_window(     
    # Use label as key     
    key_func=lambda _, l: l,          
    reduce_func=lambda _, window: window.batch(window_size),     
    window_size=window_size)
```

Now `unbatch` and then `batch` based on `batch_size`:

```
 #unbatch and batch based on batch_size
 batch_size = 8
 ds = ds.unbatch().batch(batch_size)
```

Check output,

```
for x, y in ds.take(1):
   print(x.numpy(), y.numpy())
#[b'feat_0' b'feat_1' b'feat_2' b'feat_5' b'feat_3' 
     b'feat_6' b'feat_4'b'feat_7'] [2 2 0 0 1 1 2 2]
```