# Efficiently handling time series data from multiple sources in TF.Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
time | src | a | b | c | d | e | Label
----------------------------------------
0.   | 1   | # | # | # | # | # | #
1.   | 1   | # | # | # | # | # | #
2.   | 1   | # | # | # | # | # | #
3.   | 1   | # | # | # | # | # | #
4.   | 1   | # | # | # | # | # | #
....
0.   | 2   | # | # | # | # | # | #
1.   | 2   | # | # | # | # | # | #
2.   | 2   | # | # | # | # | # | #
3.   | 2   | # | # | # | # | # | #
4.   | 2   | # | # | # | # | # | #
```

I'm training a model to predict `label` against a window of `[a,b,c,d,e]` values. So my `X` is of shape `(window_size,5)` and my `y` would be the value of `label` at the end of the window. All values of `X` must have the same value in `src` (i.e. a window of data should only come from a single source).

I've been previously compiling X/y pairs, with a little `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` to hack semi usable memory management. In looking for a better way, I found [tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array), but, based on my understanding, it would have no concept of `src`, meaning a single `X` datum could be from numerous `src`'s. How can I leverage something like `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array`, but have it only extract windows of data that have one `src` value?

note: I'd like to get a rolling window. i.e. every possible window with overlap, from each source.

---

## Progress

### 1

I successfully used `timeseries_dataset_from_array`, but it doesn't respect `src`

```
# ============= Prep ===========

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#creating numpy data structures representing the problem
X = np.random.random((100,5))
y = np.random.random((100))
src = np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50)
window_size = 5

#making a time series dataset which does not respect src
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, batch_size = 2, sequence_length=window_size, 
                                                     sequence_stride=window_size, shuffle=True)

# ============= Train ===========
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, LSTM, Flatten

#training a model, to validate the dataset is working correctly
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[window_size,5]))
model.add(LSTM(3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(Xy_ds,epochs=1)
```

### 2

Implemented mdaoust's solution, but I'm getting shape errors when training

```
# ============= Prep ===========

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#creating numpy data structures representing the problem
X = np.random.random((100,5))
y = np.random.random((100))
src = np.expand_dims(np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50),1)
window_size = 5

#appending source information to X, for filtration
X = np.append(src, X, 1)

#making a time series dataset which does not respect src
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, sequence_length=window_size, 
                                                     sequence_stride=1, shuffle=True)
def single_source(x,y):
    source = x[:,0]
    return tf.reduce_all(source == source[0])
    
#filtering by and removing src info
def drop_source(x,y):
    return x[:, 1:], y

def set_shapes(x,y, shape):
    x.set_shape(shape)
    return x,y

Xy_ds = Xy_ds.filter(single_source).map(drop_source)

# ============= Train ===========
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, LSTM, Flatten

#training a model, to validate the dataset is working correctly
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[window_size,5]))
model.add(LSTM(3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(Xy_ds,epochs=1)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_3: expected shape=(None, None, 5), found shape=(None, None, 6)
```

Presumably related to [this Github thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31373)

I tried [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31373#issuecomment-573663963) and something like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31373#issuecomment-521803286), but no dice.

Comment: have you checked - tf.data.group_by_window https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#group_by_window

Comment: Checking it out now! I think that'll do it, I just need to wrap my head around it.

Comment: i have an answer that does grouping for labels, you need to change for `src` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761829/8143158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is:

- Include the `source` as one of the coluns of `X`.
- Use `timeseries_dataset_from_array`.
- Use `filter` to drop slices that have mixed sources.

```
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(...)

def single_source(x,y):
  source = x[:,0]
  return tf.reduce_all(source == source[0])

def drop_source(x,y):
  return x[:, 1:], y

Xy_ds = Xy_ds.filter(single_source).map(drop_source)
```

Comment: I did do that in some experiments I'm running, but only for validation. this would introduce the index of the source into the input of the model, which doesn't seem ideal. I'd consider doing this if there was a coacher way then modify the dataset to remove X, but to my knowledge as of now, that does not exist.

Comment: "modify the dataset to remove X", oh, that's easy I'll update the answer.

Comment: edit: I meant to say "modify the dataset to remove the source information from Xy_ds". If you could do that, that'd be the answer, I think!

Comment: I'm most of the way there, however because execution is not happening eagerly, Xy_ds has a shape of `<MapDataset shapes: ((None, None, 6), (None,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>`, which throws errors in training, as the model expects a shape of `(None, None, 5)`

Comment: "6, should be 5" Oh, is my example checking/slicing the wrong dimension?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm adding to the 3rd dim of X so that it can contain source, then removing it. It seems like when I train the model, it still thinks the tensor is of size `(None, None 6)`. In researching on github, this is what's known as "shape missing behaviour" as a result of, presumably, just in time execution of the map function. While the map function reduces the size, TF does not know that, causing the error. I'm adding a new progress update now...

Comment: scratch that, You may have been slicing the wrong dim. I'll post update 3 when I have more info...

Comment: Eurika, Feel free to edit your answer. I'll accept yours, but post my own

Answer (score 2):

Based on mdaoust's answer, but the final working code.

## Prep

This will create the time series dataset and do all the manipulation to format it correcly

```
# ============= Prep ===========

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
batch_size = 32

#creating numpy data structures representing the problem
X = np.random.random((100,5))
y = np.random.random((100))
src = np.expand_dims(np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50),1)
window_size = 5

#appending source information to X, for filtration
X = np.append(src, X, 1)

#making a time series dataset which does not respect src
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, sequence_length=window_size, batch_size=1, 
                                                     sequence_stride=1, shuffle=True)

#filtering by and removing src info
def single_source(x,y):
    source = x[:,:,0]
    return tf.reduce_all(source == source[0])
    
def drop_source(x,y):
    x_ = x[:, :, 1:]
    print(x_)
    return x_, y

Xy_ds = Xy_ds.filter(single_source)
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.map(drop_source)
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.unbatch().batch(batch_size)

#printing the dataset
i = 0
for x, y in Xy_ds:
    i+=1
    print(x)
    print(y)
print('total batches: {}'.format(i))
```

## Training

training, just to sanity check that everything is working

```
# ============= Train ===========
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, LSTM, Flatten

#training a model, to validate the dataset is working correctly
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[window_size,5]))
model.add(LSTM(3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(Xy_ds,epochs=1)
```

Important Note: in order for this to work, batching must occur after the filter and map are applied. That's why `batch_size = 1` initially, then batching happens after.