# How do I batch a TF.Dataset without adding an additional dimension?

Tags: tensorflow

## Short:

I'm doing a variety of manipulations to a `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset` object. For a variety of reasons, I need to do several manipulations before batching the dataset. In pseudo code, I'm doing something like this:

```
# create data
X = np...
y = np...
window_size = ...

# create tf dataset
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X,y,window_size,...batch_size=1)

#doing operations
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.filter(...)
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.map(...)

#batching
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.batch(...)
```

The issue is, the shape of `Xy_ds` ends up being `(batch size, 1, window_size, n)`, presumably because I'm batching something which already has a `batch_size` of 1. How do I batch this so that the shape becomes `(batch size, window_size, n)`?

## Long:

This is the actual code I'm working with. It's essentially the pseudo code, but runable.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#creating numpy data structures representing the problem
X = np.random.random((100,5))
y = np.random.random((100))
src = np.expand_dims(np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50),1)
window_size = 10
batch_size = 3

#appending source information to X, for filtration
X = np.append(src, X, 1)

#making a time series dataset which does not respect src
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, sequence_length=window_size, batch_size=1, 
                                                     sequence_stride=1, shuffle=True)

#filtering by and removing src info
def single_source(x,y):
    source = x[:,:,0]
    return tf.reduce_all(source == source[0])
    
def drop_source(x,y):
    x_ = x[:, :, 1:]
    return x_, y

Xy_ds = Xy_ds.filter(single_source)
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.map(drop_source)

#batching
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.batch(batch_size)

i = 0
for x, y in Xy_ds:
    if i == 0:
        print('batch shape: ',x.shape)
    i+=1
print('total batches: {}'.format(i))
print('total datums: {}'.format(i*batch_size))
```

the result of the printout is

```
batch shape:  (3, 1, 10, 5)
total batches: 31
total datums: 93
```

This question is a spinoff of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803955/efficiently-handling-time-series-data-from-multiple-sources-in-tf-keras/74815001#74815001) question, if you're curious.

Comment: Maybe use `rebatch` instead of `batch`

Comment: I really did try to google the answer, read through the docs, etc. If this is a thing, and I didn't find it, I'll eat my hat.
edit: still looking into it. But swapping in `rebatch` yields `AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'rebatch'`

Comment: It's new in TF2.11,  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#rebatch

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Xy_ds = Xy_ds.unbatch().batch(batch_size)
```

src: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31548

Answer (score 0):

Also, you started with:

```
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(...batch_size=1)
```

I checked [the code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset.py#L258) and is skips batching if you set `batch size=None` Try:

```
Xy_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(...batch_size=None)
```